# How to read this notation?

Tags: notation

Under the policy $\pi(\phi,a)$, the sequence of loss functions 
\begin{equation}
L_i(\theta_i) = \mathbb{E}_{\phi,a\sim \pi(.)}[(y_i - Q_i)^2],
\end{equation}
is minimized, in order to train the Q-network.

How do I read the $\mathbb{E}_{\phi,a\sim \pi(.)}$ part? Expected $\phi,a$ based on policy $\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking with a colleague, we determined it is

> The expected value of $(y_i - Q_i)^2$ where $\phi,a$ are sampled from the policy $\pi$